# Encoding clone $this in JsonSerializable

Tags: php, recursion, clone, stack-overflow

This simplified case is resulting in a PHP segfault (exit 127):

```
class Datum implements \JsonSerializable{
  public function jsonSerialize(){
    return clone $this;
  }
}
echo json_encode(new Datum);
```

The last line of code results in exit(127). I'm unable to retrieve any stack in my current environment.

Meanwhile, removing the `clone` token works.

Is there any possible explanation why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code results in an infinite recursion.

It appears that the PHP JSON module supports `JsonSerializable` in this manner (pseudocode):

```
function json_encode($data){
    if($data instanceof JsonSerializable) return json_encode($data->jsonSerialize());
    else real_json_encode($data); // handling primitive data or arrays or pure data objects
}
```

If you return yet another instance of JsonSerializable, json_encode is going to try to serialize it again, resulting in an infinite recursion.

This is working for `return $this;`, however, probably due to intentional workaround from json_encode's implementation where it goes straight to real json_encode when the returned object is identical, i.e. when `$this` is returned. However this is not happening for cloned objects since `$a !== clone $a`.

### References

This answer can be supported by reference from the php-src.

```
// in php_json_encode_zval
if (instanceof_function(Z_OBJCE_P(val), php_json_serializable_ce)) {
    return php_json_encode_serializable_object(buf, val, options, encoder);
}

// in php_json_encode_serializable_object
if ((Z_TYPE(retval) == IS_OBJECT) &&
    (Z_OBJ(retval) == Z_OBJ_P(val))) {
    /* Handle the case where jsonSerialize does: return $this; by going straight to encode array */
    PHP_JSON_HASH_APPLY_PROTECTION_DEC(myht);
    return_code = php_json_encode_array(buf, &retval, options, encoder);
} else {
    /* All other types, encode as normal */
    return_code = php_json_encode_zval(buf, &retval, options, encoder);
    PHP_JSON_HASH_APPLY_PROTECTION_DEC(myht);
}
```

These snippets prove that PHP would encode `return $this;` as an array (or as a non-serializable object), while returning anything else makes `Z_OBJ(retval) == Z_OBJ_P(val)` false, going to the `else` block which recursively calls `php_json_encode_zval` again.

## TL;DR, Simple solution: `return (array) $this;` instead of `clone $this;`.